# PixelSnapping on movieclips/sprites

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to apply PixelSnapping on movieclips/sprites and not just on bitmaps? Caching them as bitmap doesn't help. Any trick?

[image: Gap between two movieclips on low quality]

Comment: whats inside the clips? Could it be the x/y values of the clip children rather than the clip itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its during motions, you an try by using a tween engine like [TweenLite](https://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), that has a property to round the modified properties of your items during the movement.

If you're just trying to have round positions of things like that, you can try to round manually the properties when modifying them :

```
myClip.x = Math.round(myClip.x);
```

or just

```
myClip.x = int(myClip.x)
```

Comment: No, that did not help me. The movieclips are perfectly placed on rounded x and y positions. That did not cause the problem. The problem starts when the quality is on low, and the gaps only appear when the swf is at 100% zoom. If I zoom, the gap will disappear.

Comment: I'd say that low quality is tricky to handle. Have you tried to set your objets width to the right dimension + 0.5 px ? Maybe the Flash Player would then "round" them while displaying to something more like you'd want ?... (since Low quality is basically displaying the Stage like if it had less pixels than the normal quality...)